# Grammar use and when to use

Tags: grammar

‘Hasn’t’ or ‘didn’t’? I want to know which is correct when used in the sentence ‘he hasn’t been hurt’ or ‘he didn’t get hurt‘.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both are grammatically correct.

Has been or hasn't been are present perfect tense. It refers to an action that began at some time in the past and is still in progress.

*Example: "It hasn't been used very much, but it has worked".*

Didn't is the past tense of 'do'. This means that in the past something was known.
"He didn't get hurt." The person talking knows that he wasn't hurt.

*Example:
I didn’t know the answer. - simple past negative (Subject + didn’t + base of an active verb)*